# Limited access to a directory's contents

Tags: files, permissions, directory

There is a file in a directory that me and the other users want to be able to read. I want the other users not to be able to see the other files in the directory. They should be able to read a specific file in a directory if they know the name of the file.

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: Is there such a command to make this easy.

Comment: explain what do you need exactly, will never know your question if its in your mind.

Comment: you need to create a file and then assign a permission to that file.So that the user can access it.

Comment: There is a file in the directory that me and the other users want to be able to read. i want The other users don't see the other files in the directory. they are able to read a specific file in a directory if he / she knows the name of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to create a directory which other members of your group cannot list, but where you can make files accessible to them anyway... Accessing a directory requires the "execute" permission, listing its contents requires the "read" permission. If you make a directory executable but not readable, users can access files stored within but can't list its contents.

Given a `shared` group:

```
mkdir -m710 demo
chgrp shared demo
echo "secret" > demo/file1
chmod 640 demo/file1
```

Then other users in the `shared` group will be able to view the contents of `demo/file1`, but `ls demo` will fail.

Note that if others guess the names of other files, they will be able to access those files, if they have the permission. So make sure to keep the other files private.

Comment: Yes, that what i was looking for. thanks :) .